# dump from OpenERP Python is harmless?

Tags: python, odoo

I am getting this dump occasionally from OpenERP, but it seems harmless. The code serves HTTP; is this dump what happens when a connection is dropped?

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('10.100.2.71', 42799)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 640, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 693, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just means that the underlying TCP connection was abruptly dropped. In this case it means that you are trying to write data to a socket that has already been closed on the other side (by the client). It is harmless, it means that while your server was sending an HTTP response to the client (browser) she stopped the request (closed the browser for example).